# Distributed Locking

Tags: c++, database, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, distributed-transactions

I have 3 Process (P1, P2, and P3) each running on different machines. These process share 3 tables (T1, T2 and T3) in database. While updating these tables I need to maintain the atomicity of 3 tables at once ( Either all tables should be modified or none of the tables should be modified). My database does not provide lock for updating multiple tables at once.

How can this operation be performed efficiently ? What is the common used solution for this problem.

I can create a separate table in Database to act as mutex. Writing 1 when any process is running and 0 when the process exits. But even with this solution, when process 1 just releases the mutex, process 2 and process 3 can simultaneously enter the critical section.

I can use the double lock check to solve the problem.

Is there any simpler solution to this problem ?
Is there any already existing API in any library ?

Comment: Are you aiming for a specific OS, or do you need a generic solution?

Comment: @Lior Kogan - I am looking the solution for Linux OS . Even , the generic solution would be fine.

Comment: Which db you are using?

Comment: @Jacky I am using GridDB

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing this using mutex stored in db it will be less efficient in my opinion. since db write takes more time than OS varibales like Mutexes.

If you are implementing from client side, and if communicating with client process are possible,
You can create independent mutexes for each process's tables.
And implement you mutex lock function as to lock your table edit, send lock message to the other 2 tables in the remaining processes.

Locking should done only if the two other processes locked their table successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not like the regular distributed transaction since the transaction does not spanning several nodes or partitions.

The behavior of GridDB is similar to MongoDB, which only support single-document level atomic. A common technique used is two-phase commits, you could refers to [Perform Two Phase commits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) for details

> Note that two-phase commits can only offer transaction-like semantics. It is possible for applications to return intermediate data at intermediate points during the two-phase commit or rollback.